# Como obtener elementos de un array de forma ordenada y no aleatoriamente?

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, ordenamiento, random

Este script sortea aleatoriamente un mensaje de la lista `status` cuando la función `run` es ejecutada

```js
var robot = {
  status:[
    {message:"message 1"},
    {message:"message 2"},
    {message:"message 3"},
    {message:"message 4"},
    {message:"message 5"},
    {message:"message 6"},
    {message:"message 7"},
    {message:"message 8"},
    {message:"message 9"},
    {message:"message 0"},
  ]
};

function mixer(list) {
  var a = list.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  });
  a.reverse();
  a = a.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  });
  return a;
}

function run() {
  var a = mixer(robot.status);
  robot.selection = a[0].message;

  console.log(robot.selection);
}

run();
```

Necesito ayuda para que el script obtenga los mensajes de la lista de manera ordenada, o sea que cuando la función `run` sea ejecutada por primera vez me devuelva el primer mensaje de la lista, luego al ejecutar nuevamente la función `run` me devuelva el segundo después el tercero y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al final de la lista, y de ser posible que una vez llegado al final (que pueden ser hasta 100 valores como máximo) se retome nuevamente al primer mensaje volviendo a empezar haciendo un loop infinito. Las desventajas que tengo con el método aleatorio es que a veces se repiten los valores entre ejecución y ejecución y algunos valores nunca se sortean algunos valores

### **Trabaja desde Google Apps Script**

Es una Aplicación Web que ejecuta sus funciones mediante Activadores o "triggers" basados en el tiempo y de forma automática y no tiene nada que ver con html o php ya que no se encuentra en un sitio web público sino que es un archivo oculto que se desempeña 100% desde la nube alojándose en Google Drive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí los resultados de 2 ejecuciones para mostrarles los resultados random**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado por internet soluciones y he intentado varios métodos sin tener buenos resultados.
Agradecería la ayuda de ustedes ... saludos

Disculpen mi ignorancia si me confundo en algunos términos, traté de ser lo mas claro posible

Comment: Lo del `loop infinito` no tiene sentido, no terminaría nunca.

Comment: ¿Que sentido tiene hacerlo de forma ordenada si al final va a estar desordenado (_u ordenado de forma aleatoria_)? ¿por que necesitas hacerlo así?

Comment: Es decir, ¿crees que al procesar de forma ordenada e ir ordenando aleatoriamente los mensajes la probabilidad de que no se repitan va a ser menor?

Comment: Puede que haya un problema con el uso que le estas dando palabra [`sort`](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=es&text=sort&op=translate) y que quiere decir ordenar. ¿Necesitas "_imprimir / listar / mostrar_" de forma ordenada los mensaje sin que se repitan y una vez que llegas al último empezar de nuevo?

Comment: No hay problema, solo intento entender que es lo que necesitas hacer. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y reformularla? ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Aún no te puedo ayudar con eso, porque todavía no entiendo exactamente que es lo que quisieras obtener

Comment: Comentario totalmente no relacionado: sortear existe en español y significa algo muy diferente a ordenar. Preguntar también es usar las palabras correctas ;)  Pa' qué _sorting_ si se puede ordenar? :D

Comment: @Alfabravo, muy atinado tu comentario jajaja :D

Answer (score 4):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var robot={
status:[
{message:"message 1"},
{message:"message 2"},
{message:"message 3"},
{message:"message 4"},
{message:"message 5"},
{message:"message 6"},
{message:"message 7"},
{message:"message 8"},
{message:"message 9"},
{message:"message 0"},
]
};
// configuramos en -1
// le sumamos 1 antes de enviar
// -1 + 1 =  0;
last_index=-1;
// ordenar
robot.status.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.message > b.message;
});

function mixer(list){
var a=list.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
a.reverse();
a=a.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
return a;
}

// envia la siguiente posicion
function next(){
  // longitud del arreglo
  let array_size = Object.keys(robot.status).length;
  // validamos que llego al ultimo
  if(last_index == array_size-1){
     // volvemos a configurar a -1
     last_index = -1;
  }
  // le suamos +1  y enviamos el indice
  return ++last_index;
}

function run(){
//var a= mixer(robot.status);
//console.log(a)
let index = next();
r = robot.status[index].message;
console.log(r);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">click</button>
```

Comment: @DjMarkitos sale es un error de sort() pero yo no puedo editarlo...

Comment: ya corregi debe funcionarte.... [enlace](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1ebXuumtQeDXcox1l92kH1hkzchAl8QzInnFYBCPLXQmQ3lrfaqo9mOk6/edit) te muestra 1 porque cada vez que das run se ejecuta desde el inicio con un for puedes ver que si funciona correctamente

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona correctamente, en cada clic del botón se muestran los mensajes en orden y vuelve a iniciar. No afecta si se ejecuta directamente y después se hace clic en el botón. +1

Comment: @DjMarkitos, borré mi respuesta porque cuando la publiqué no me di cuenta que funciona exactamente igual que esta, lo único diferente fue que use `setInterval()` para ejecutar en lugar de un botón.

Comment: @DjMarkitos, esta respuesta funciona correctamente, solo quita el botón y ejecuta `run()` con tus activadores.

Comment: @DjMarkitos, no puedes ver mi respuesta porque la borré y fue porque ya se había publicado esta y hace exactamente lo mismo que la mía. ¿Para qué queremos dos respuestas iguales? Si algo no te funciona, modifica tu pregunta con el código actualizado y menciona exactamente qué es lo que está fallando.